# Should I capitalize GAM, MARS and LOESS?

Tags: notation, generalized-additive-model, loess, mars

I have to mention GAM (generalized additive models), MARS (multivariate adaptive regression splines), and LOESS in an academic paper.

I think GAM and MARS are capitalized in most cases, but not sure about LOESS.
I saw LOESS, Loess, and loess all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[LOESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) is an acronym of *locally weighted scatterplot smoothing* and as such is commonly written in uppercase. On another hand, some acronyms are written in lowercase and the rules are not that clear cut, as noticed e.g. in [The Economist style guide](http://www.economist.com/style-guide/abbreviations):

> Abbreviations that can be pronounced and are composed of bits of words
>   rather than just initials should be spelt out in upper and lower case:
>   Cocom, Frelimo, Kfor, Legco, Mercosur, Nepad, Renamo, Sfor, Unicef,
>   Unison, Unprofor, Trips (trade-related aspects of intellectual
>   property rights). There is generally no need for more than one initial
>   capital letter, unless the word is a company or a trade name: MiG,
>   ConsGold. (...)
>
> Most upper-case abbreviations take upper-case initial letters when
>   written in full (eg, the LSO is the London Symphony Orchestra), but
>   there are exceptions: CAP but common agricultural policy, EMU but
>   economic and monetary union, GDP but gross domestic product, PSBR but
>   public-sector borrowing requirement, VLSI but very large-scale
>   integration.

See also https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/51924/proper-capitalization-of-commonly-used-acronyms

Comment: LOESS being an acronym of locally weighted scatterplot smoothing may not be correct. Based on [this discussion](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/What-does-LOESS-stand-for-td2237086.html), LOESS actually stands for "local regression models".